# Ruby Compile error Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, windows, ruby

Getting this error when using `nmake` on Windows7 x64 to compile Ruby 2.2.0

I've never done this before, so I have been following [this](http://bunkernetz.com/2014/05/23/building-ruby-2-1-x64-on-windows-8/) and [this](http://madcoderspeak.blogspot.co.uk/2009/06/how-to-compile-ruby-from-source-on.html) advice:

```
generating ripper-x64-mswin64_100.def
NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make '../../probes.h'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0
\VC\Bin\amd64\nmake.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.

C:\Users\Richard\Downloads\Ruby\ruby-2.2.0-build>
```

I believe the problem has to do with the placement of the file, as indicated by `nmake`'s inability to invoke the `cd` command. I'll be looking at this further, but wondered if anyone had experience with it?

Answer (score 1):

Found the fix - put `probes.h` in the build folder (`nmake` looks for it there)